# Which thread-parallel interface to use for task sharing and splitting using a stack?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, tbb

I am planning to write a code where I want to share the work using tasks which can be split. In a serial version, I use a stack initialised with the root task. The stack is emptied by repeatedly popping a task, which is then either performed or split and the sub-tasked pushed back on the stack. What is the best (most efficient and effortless) way and interface (tbb, openmp, etc) to implement this in parallel? Is a parallel stack like this explicitly supported by any thread-parallel interface (or is there a better alternative to a stack)?

Comment: hm.. you might want to look at [openmp task features](http://wikis.sun.com/display/openmp/Using+the+Tasking+Feature), especially at `Use single to start parallel region with a root task`. Here you could pop for each element in your stack a task.

Comment: task_group in tbb / ppl should be able to do this easily.

Comment: Do you need the lifo behaviour of the stack, or is fifo or unspecified good enough for you?

Comment: Are the tasks independent? What do you mean by "can be split"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are actually describing is a work-stealing queue. This has started with the Cilk programming language (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cilk) and continues with Cilk++ that is part of the Intel Compiler. You can get a free evaluation version for Linux.

Intel TBB also features a work-stealing queue and supports automatic splitting of tasks, plus additional control if you want to split them yourself. OpenMP does not have this kind of control but I don't think it is impossible to do.

There is also qthreads from Sandia (https://code.google.com/p/qthreads/) which a nice package that allows you to have an M:N scheduler (M user level threads on N OS threads).